# Socket Client + Threading + Android + connection Status's

Tags: java, android, sockets, client

I am very new to both java, and Android development, and I am designing a android client to send messages to a server, and receive messages back from the server. It only performs a few functions, first it will query the server for its initial status, it will then use that status to update a button, and a charging symbol to say if the charger is charging or not. I have got all of the communication code to work  and the thread seems to send and recieve messages well enough, but variables outside of the thread are not being updated, and if I shut the server connection down, the client will keep a connection open, as if the server is still there. Could anybody give me some advice, to fix my problems?

```
package charger.app;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class ChargeTabActivity extends Activity {

String serverIp = "192.168.6.120"; //server Ip address  
private static String preqon = "control:Charger:1\r\n"; //sets connection to turn charger on
private static String preqoff = "control:Charger:0\r\n";    //Turn charger off
public boolean connected = false; //connection 

//set up buttons
private ImageButton chargeOnOff;
private ImageButton connectButton;

//Set it so that Client Functions can be accessed from main program
ClientFunctions functions = new ClientFunctions();



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //initialize UI
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //declare buttons for listeners, and display changes        
    connectButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.connectButton);       
        connectButton.setOnClickListener(connectButtonListener);    
    chargeOnOff = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.chargeOnOff);  
        chargeOnOff.setOnClickListener(chargeOnOffListener);
    Button chargeStatus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.chargeStatus);



    ////set up strict mode off/////
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.
                ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


}



/*Listens to see if the connect button is pressed, if it is connected it will 
 * display connected, else it will try and connect*/
private OnClickListener connectButtonListener = new OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if (connected) 
        {
            toast("I am connected");
        }
        else 
        {
            toast("I am not connected");
        }
    }
};


/*Listens to see if the Charge on Off Button is pressed, if it is charging it will 
 * send a request to charge, else it will send a request to stop the charge*/
private OnClickListener chargeOnOffListener = new OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    { 
        //ask server
        try {
            functions.updateStatus();  //updates the charger status
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Client","Trouble querying",e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //send message to turn server on or off
        if (functions.chargeStatNumber != 0) 
        {
            try {
                functions.sendMessage(preqoff);
                chargeOnOff.setImageResource(R.drawable.charge_on);
                toast("Turning Charger off");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }//end if


        else 
        {
            try {
                functions.sendMessage(preqon);
                chargeOnOff.setImageResource(R.drawable.charge_off);
                toast("Turning Charger on");

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        } //end else

        Log.d("ClientActivity", "Charge Button hit" );


        //ask server about its status
        try {
            functions.updateStatus();  //updates the charger status
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Client","Trouble querying",e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
};


/////When Application Starts
@Override
public void onStart() 
{
    super.onStart();

    Thread cThread = new Thread(new serverThread()); //Starts the thread that initiates communications
    cThread.start();
};

////////On Pause//////This is when a user makes another app, the center point of attention 
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    functions.closeConnection();

};

//////On Resume/////This is used for when an app exits, and then the user brings it back
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


};

//////On Destroy//////////
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    functions.closeConnection();

};



//toast messages
public void toast(String toastMessage) 
{
    Toast.makeText(DelphiChargeTabActivity.this, toastMessage,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
};



//Thread to run and receive network connections

public class serverThread implements Runnable 
{
    public boolean connected = false; //connection
    public void run() //runs the thread
    {

        try 
        {
            functions.connectToServer(serverIp); //connects to server
            connected = true;

            while (connected) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    connectButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_car);
                    functions.getStreams(); //establish stream connections
                    functions. updateStatus(); //updates the status of the server
                    //checkChangeChargeButton(); //sets initial state for charge button



                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(2500);
                    }
                          catch ( InterruptedException interruptedException ) 
                          {
                             functions.displayMessage( "\nThread exception" );
                          } // end catch

                }
                    catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                        Log.e("Client","Trouble Getting Streams",e);

                    }



            }//end while
        }//end try
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Client", "Error Connecting", e);
                connected = false;
                connectButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_car);

            }
    }; //end run
}; //end serverThread

public void checkChangeChargeButton() 
{

    if (functions.chargeStatNumber != 0) 
    {
        chargeOnOff.setImageResource(R.drawable.charge_on);
    }
    else 
    {
        chargeOnOff.setImageResource(R.drawable.charge_off);
    }

};



} //This is the Activity close bracket
```

This is the code for my function methods

```
    package charger.app;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.util.Log;


public class ClientFunctions
{

private String message;
private String server;
public Socket sock;
private PrintWriter writer;
private DataInputStream inStream;
public Boolean connected;
private String encode = "UTF8";
public byte[] chargerstat;
public int  chargeStatNumber; //Used to set the array byte 15 to an int


//inquires server for status of charge
public void updateStatus() throws IOException 
{
    //Prompt user for server command
    System.out.println("Sending request for Charger status data.");
        String serverMessage = "meas:Charger?\r\n";

    // send the message
        sendMessage("meas:Charger?\r\n");
        System.out.println();
        displayMessage(serverMessage + "sent");

    // now receive the message
    receiveMessage();
        displayMessage("Receive complete");


};


public void connectToServer(String serverIp) throws IOException  //Server IP is sent in main    app as String "serverIp"
{
    //set server IP

    //display logcat trying to connect
    displayMessage("\nTrying to Connect");
    //Start Socket Connection
    sock = new Socket( InetAddress.getByName( serverIp ), 18088);
    //Display connected
    displayMessage( "\nConnected to: " + 
             sock.getInetAddress().getHostName() );



};

public void getStreams() throws IOException 
{
    //Set up PrintWriter
    writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new            OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream())),true);
    writer.flush();
    //Set Up I
    inStream = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
    //display Message Got I/O
    displayMessage("\nGot IO Streams");

};

public void sendMessage(final String serverMessage) throws UnsupportedEncodingException 
{


    //set variable for message
    message = serverMessage;
    //sends message
    writer.printf("%s", message);
    writer.flush();
    //display message sent
    displayMessage("\nsent" /*+ serverMessage*/);




};

public static int getInt(byte[] array, int offset) 
  {
    return
      ((array[offset+3]   & 0xff) << 24) |
      ((array[offset+2] & 0xff) << 16) |
      ((array[offset+1] & 0xff) << 8) |
       (array[offset] & 0xff);
  }


public void receiveMessage() throws IOException 
{
    {
        int c=0;
        int i;          
        int seqcountval;

        chargerstat = new byte[96];
        i=0;
        while(i < 96)
        {
            try
            {
                c = inStream.read();
                chargerstat[i] = (byte)c;
            }
            catch ( IOException ioException ) 
            {
                ioException.printStackTrace();
            } // end catch
// uncomment this to see each byte          
            //displayMessage(":" + i + " " + chargerstat[i]);
            i++;
        }

        seqcountval = getInt(chargerstat, 76);
        displayMessage("SeqCntr = " + seqcountval);
        chargeStatNumber = chargerstat[15];

    };
};

public  void closeConnection() 
{
    //closes connections
    displayMessage("\n\nClosing Connection");

    try 
    {
        writer.close();
        inStream.close();
        sock.close();


    }
    catch ( IOException ioException ) 
      {
         ioException.printStackTrace();
      } // end catch


};



public void displayMessage( final String messageToDisplay )
   {

         new Runnable()
         {
            public void run() // updates displayArea
            {
              //change to log.d for android
                System.out.println(messageToDisplay);
            } // end method run
         };  // end anonymous inner class

   } // end method displayMessage





};
```

Comment: Which variables outside of the thread are not being updated? Why do you say the client keeps a connection to the server (what is the indication)?

Comment: Sorry, my connected variable, as well as my chargerstat[15], do not seem to always be updated outside of the thread, and I think I have an issue exiting the connected status when the connection is cut on one end.

Comment: The connected inside ServerThread is a different connected than that in ChargerActivity. They are not related in any way.

Comment: Ok thank you for the information, this has been a very helpful site during my adventures

Comment: It's a great site. It will work even well for you if you accept or upvote the answers that helped you or solved your problems. It will make your accept ratio go up and encourage more people to help you.
That said, accept when you are convinced that your problem is solved.
Upvote when you gained insight from an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use AsyncTask instead of a Thread, it will be much easier to share info and seems applicable to what you're trying to do.

> Using AsyncTask
>
> AsyncTask allows you to perform asynchronous work on your user
>   interface. It performs the blocking operations in a worker thread and
>   then publishes the results on the UI thread, without requiring you to
>   handle threads and/or handlers yourself.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html

Your "connected" variable in ChargerActivity is different from that in your ServerThread hence ChargerActivity's connected won't be updated from the thread.

Answer (score 1):

socket function can't be used in ui thread after android 4.0, such as your connect funciton and  sendMessage

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update UI from different thread. You have to update UI in the main thread. If you want to update UI from different thread, you can do something like this

```
public void changeButtonImage(){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            connectButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_car);
        }});
}
```